# Restore Old User Account from files

Tags: macos, restore, user-account

I have an old MBP (2008) and I've been updating the OS after waiting for so long.

I installed Yosemite recently, and am now installing El Capitan. Idiotically, I forgot to make a backup before doing this, and of course this installation will give me problems.

The El Capitan installation failed twice, so I used Safe Boot to create a new account and get access my old files.

However, my old files are organized strangely; my old user account is now just a regular folder in /Users/, and all my old applications/library/system files are in a "Recovered Items" folder.

**Is there any way to restore my old account using these two folders?**

**Summary:**

```
*Home Folder > Regular folder in /Users/ (Has an Applications folder, but is empty)
*Applications > In /Macintosh HD/Recovered Items/
*Library > In /Macintosh HD/Recovered Items/
*System > In /Macintosh HD/Recovered Items/
```

It would save me the hassle of re-installing all of my programs and settings.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If an account has been deleted but your homefolder is still present in /Users/, you can create an account with the exact same user name and it will ask if you'd like to use the home folder with that name for the new user.

Comment: @QMord - I wish I had known that. I eventually used a really old time machine backup to just start fresh. Almost all my files are kept on an external, so no real loss. Just have to reinstall everything now. Thanks for your help.